# Camera.open() возвращает NPE

Tags: java, android, камера

В своем проекте делаю кастомную камеру, но столкнулся с небольшой проблемой, которая в свою очередь проявляется только на андроид-ах 6 версий. Вот метод получение экземпляра класса камеры, который я вызываю во фрагменте:

```
private Camera getCameraInstance() {
        Camera camera = null;
        try {
            camera = Camera.open();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // cannot get camera or does not exist
        }
        return camera;
    }
```

Если перейти в тело метода `open()`, то увидим следующий код:

```
 public static Camera open() {
            int numberOfCameras = getNumberOfCameras();
            CameraInfo cameraInfo = new CameraInfo();
            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCameras; i++) {
                getCameraInfo(i, cameraInfo);
                if (cameraInfo.facing == CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK) {
                    return new Camera(i);
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Под дебагом находится две камеры. И вызывается `return new Camera(i);`, но во фрагмент отчего-то null возвращается, что не поддается никакому объяснению(по крайней мере для меня). Еще раз повторюсь, что на четвертых и пятых версиях всё работает корректно. То что нагуглил - ничего не помогло.

Comment: Разрешение запрашиваете? https://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: трейс пожалуйста

Comment: @YuraIvanov Вы правы, уже начал копать в это направлении, в 6-ках надо запрашивать разрешения в рантайме.

Comment: @YuraIvanov Вы можете опубликовать как ответ, я помечу его правильным

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для Android-M следует в рантайме запрашивать разрешения. Например, сразу три разрешения:

```
private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST=1;
....
private void checkCamera(){
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext,
                Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(context,
                    new String[]{
                            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                            Manifest.permission.CAMERA
                    },
                    PERMISSION_REQUEST);
        } else {
            useCamera();
        }
    } else {
        useCamera();
    }
}
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode == PERMISSION_REQUEST) {
        if (grantResults.length > 0
                && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && grantResults[2] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            useCamera();
        }
    }
}
```

См. также https://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/permissions/requesting.html

Answer (score 2):

Судя по исходникам этот конструктор может бросать исключения:

```
Camera(int cameraId) {
    int err = cameraInitNormal(cameraId);
    if (checkInitErrors(err)) {
        switch(err) {
            case EACCESS:
                throw new RuntimeException("Fail to connect to camera service");
            case ENODEV:
                throw new RuntimeException("Camera initialization failed");
            default:
                // Should never hit this.
                throw new RuntimeException("Unknown camera error");
        }
    }
}
```

Основываясь на вашем коде, объект камеры будет NULL в этом случае.